# Should left outer joins be avoided in DB2

Tags: database, db2, left-join

We are having a debate in our company.  I use left outer joins quit frequently.  I was told by another programmer that there is too much over head and I should not use them.  Example, Lets say I have two tables, they would rather me hit the database twice get the information I need from each table store it in memory and join the data on the java side, instead of just doing a left outer join.  I think this is absurd and would be bad for performance.  Am I wrong

Comment: Profile both approaches and let the numbers speak for themselves.

Comment: That programmer should be fired!

Comment: I ran into exactly this example, and a strobe report (Cobol v. Java, but bound SQL is bound SQL) showed that 50% of the time spent was running the second query that should have been left joined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used to do joins in the application rather than in the database sometimes back in the 80s.  But really, by 1988 or so the database optimizer was usually good enough with DB2 that wasn't necessary any more.

I can't think of any ordinary scenarios that warrant application-joins.  Abnormal situations like when you've got an over-loaded database server, fat network pipe, a ton of capacity on the app server, and a bunch of new queries - might warrant it for some of the queries.  Maybe.

But in general joins, including left/right/full outer joins are your friend.  They allow you to have smaller tables, get better use out of both storage and memory, etc.  But you do want up to date statistics, to have a passing familiarity with the kinds of access paths a database uses and get in the habit of doing explains.

Answer (score 4):

You are not wrong. Using a join is most likely to be more efficient. This is what databases are good at.

Comment: That was my exact argument to the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

My belief is that you should avoid hitting the database twice when you don't need to. I fail to see where a left join would be more of a problem than asking for the data twice. If the FKs are not indexed there could be a performance problem, but that is poor design not a fault of the left joins.

Eventually the same amount of data would have to be returned one way or the other and databases are designed to use joins.

That said, it could be that the way you are writing the queries might not be efficient (using left joins when inner joins are needed or joining to tables not needed at all), without seeing them I have no way to know that.

Comment: I use left outer joins if I want data from the left table to always be there and want data from the right table only if it exist.  I would use an inner join if the data must exist in both tables to be returned.